# ReactJS: how to pass function name by prop in object to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a function name , that will be used by another componenet in object , passing it through prop , but however function exists in the componenet that it is passed to I can't invoke it by the name i passed.

app.js

```
<div className="ui container five column grid taskList">
  {tasks.map(function(entry,idx) {
    return(
      <Task key={idx} 
        message={entry} 
        deleteTask={this.handleDelete} 
        renameTask={this.handleRename} 
        saveTask={this.handleSave} 
        openTask={this.handleOpen} 
        entryNum={idx} 
        iconSetup={{
          icon1:{ inClass:'expand', clickFun:this.openCurrentTask },
          icon2:{ inClass:["save","saveTask"], clickFun:this.saveCurrentTask },
          icon3:{ inClass:["trash","outline"], clickFun:this.removeCurrentTask }
        }}
      />
    )
  },this)}
</div>
```

task.js

```
export class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.dataChanged = this.dataChanged.bind(this);
    this.removeCurrentTask = this.removeCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.saveCurrentTask = this.saveCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.openCurrentTask = this.openCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      message: this.props.message
    }
  }
  saveCurrentTask () {
    this.props.saveTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  customValidateText (text) {
    return (text.length > 0 && text.length < 31);
  }

  dataChanged(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
    this.props.renameTask(data.message,this.props.entryNum);
    this.setState({ message: data.message });
  }

  removeCurrentTask () {
    this.props.deleteTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  openCurrentTask () {
    this.props.openTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  render () {
    const centerRow = classNames('textCenter', 'row'),
          iconSetup = this.props.iconClasses,
          domIcons = [];
    for (let icon in iconSetup) {
      if (iconSetup.hasOwnProperty(icon)) {
        let element = iconSetup[icon];
        domIcons.push(<Icon className={classNames('large', element['inClass'])} onClick={element['clickFun']}/>)
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className={centerRow}>
        {domIcons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the classNames getting pass as they should , but onClick=undefined

I tried adding .bind(this) , .bind(null,this) but none of those worked instead they crashed whole app once component was mounted.

Comment: It's because you are referencing functions of the `Task` component in your `App` component with a this referencing to the `App` You have to either declare functions in the `App` component or change the way you want to call them if they stay inside the `Task` component

Comment: could you show me some example pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I don't think it's the best way to accomplish this but I'll try to stick to your structure. You'll probably want to learn more about [React composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

```
<div className="ui container five column grid taskList">
  {tasks.map(function (entry,idx) {
    return(
      <Task key={idx} 
        message={entry} 
        deleteTask={this.handleDelete} 
        renameTask={this.handleRename} 
        saveTask={this.handleSave} 
        openTask={this.handleOpen} 
        entryNum={idx} 
        iconSetup={{
          icon1:{ inClass: 'expand', clickFun: 'open' },
          icon2:{ inClass: ["save", "saveTask"], clickFun: 'save' },
          icon3:{ inClass: ["trash", "outline"], clickFun: 'remove' }
        }}
      />
    )
  },this)}
</div>
```

task.js

```
export class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.dataChanged = this.dataChanged.bind(this);
    this.removeCurrentTask = this.removeCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.saveCurrentTask = this.saveCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.openCurrentTask = this.openCurrentTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      message: this.props.message
    }
  }
  saveCurrentTask () {
    this.props.saveTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  customValidateText (text) {
    return (text.length > 0 && text.length < 31);
  }

  dataChanged(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
    this.props.renameTask(data.message,this.props.entryNum);
    this.setState({ message: data.message });
  }

  removeCurrentTask () {
    this.props.deleteTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  openCurrentTask () {
    this.props.openTask(this.props.entryNum);
  }
  render () {
    const centerRow = classNames('textCenter', 'row'),
          dictionary = {
               open: this.openCurrentTask ,
               save: this.saveCurrentTask ,
               remove: this.removeCurrentTask 
            },
          iconSetup = this.props.iconClasses,
          domIcons = [];
    for (let icon in iconSetup) {
      if (iconSetup.hasOwnProperty(icon)) {
        let element = iconSetup[icon];
        domIcons.push(<Icon className={classNames('large', element['inClass'])} onClick={dictionary[element.clickFun]}/>)
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className={centerRow}>
        {domIcons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works well thanks :) , i just wonder what is causing the "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." , i bet thats <Icon>'s componenets inside of domIcons arr , do you have idea how to add keys while using for in loop ?

Comment: Simply add the key prop as the message says : `<Icon key={whateverIsUniqueForThisComponent} />`. Do not hesitate to read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)